# Fuel rail pressure port size on 1985 Porsche 911

Tags: fuel-system, porsche, 911

What fitting do I need to attach my pressure gauge (female 1/8" NPT) to the port on the fuel rail?

I know the port is metric but I'm not sure of the size.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that NPT is a US standard for pipes and fittings. There is a Wikipedia page showing different conversions of the [NPT standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_pipe_thread#Table_of_standard_sizes).

Comment: I'm looking specifically for information on the metric side - like diameter and thread pitch. I'm hoping to find an adapter fitting.

Comment: Yes, I realised that after I commented and reread your question. I might find units and sizes for early 80s but not sure about specifically 1985 911.